# Table column name with regular expression using mysql

Tags: mysql

Please let me know is that possible i am use regular expression or another idea to set query like,

```
select name_en,name_ar,desc_en,desc_ar from table_name
```

in above query i need to write all column name but should be required directly
column name have _en or _ar not want to specify all column name.

Comment: One idea is to use: [14.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) and [22.4 The INFORMATION_SCHEMA COLUMNS Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html).

Comment: Yes, it is great. if is that possible then please more elaborate with any one query example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with `mysql_list_fields()` function and get your fields name from the table.

Comment: Thank You, You save me my lot of time.

Comment: Oh Good, i will sure try to get help from you